# Consuming SOA Suite WSDL SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soa-suite

here is what I got: 
installed and configured SOA Suite 11g, (weblogic server 10.3, repository creation utility, soa suite, jdeveloper studio, Oracle XE database 10g).

> SOA infrastructure Service engines (BPEL, Mediator, Business rules,
>   Himan workflow Metadastore (MDS) Enterprise manager, web service
>   manager, B2B, Adapterframework (JCA) Oracle Business Activity
>   monitoring (BAM)

All set up and running. tutorial project Purchase Order Processing set up and running as well (its' from book "Getting started with Oracle SOA suite 11g R1 A hands on tutorial").

Tests are executing fine, all passed (several types of credit cards, small, medium and large orders, automatic and manual approval, several types on shipping automatically chosen on size of order etc.)

[image]

What I want now is to connect - consume - that service from palin JAVA application.
Following this tutorial (http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jax-ws/create-and-consume-web-service-using-jax-ws/) 
I managed use JAX-WS tool called ‘wsimport’ for generating the artifacts required for creating and consuming a web service. 
‘wsimport’ takes a wsdl file as input.
It compiled well besides one warning for what I think is not critical  (or maybe it is?)

> C:\Users\Nenad\eclipseJunoSESR2\GettingStartedWithEclipseJuno\SOAConsume02>wsimport
>   -s src -d bin http://i3770k.mshome.net:8001/soa-infra/services/default/POProcessing/receivePO?WSDL
>
> parsing WSDL...
>
> [WARNING] R2716 WSI-BasicProfile ver. 1.0, namespace attribute not
>   allowed in doc/lit for soapbind:body: "execute"   line 31 of
>   http://i3770k.mshome.net:8001/soa-infra/services/default/POProcessing/receivePO?WSDL
>
> generating code... compiling code...
>
> C:\Users\Nenad\eclipseJunoSESR2\GettingStartedWithEclipseJuno\SOAConsume02>

So the classes are there:

[image]

And now I am stuck, because I have no idea how to send "order" i.e. how to populate input arguments:

> request PurchaseOrderType 
>   * CustID string   Value
>   * ID string   Value  productName string  itemType string  price decimal  quantity decimal   status string  ccType string  ccNumber

**In eclipse I created SOAClient class such as:**

```
package com.oracle.client;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import com.oracle.sca.soapservice.poprocessing.poprocessing.receivepo.ReceivePO;
import com.oracle.xmlns.ns.order.PurchaseOrderType;

public class SOAClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ReceivePO receivePO = new ReceivePO();
        PurchaseOrderType pot = new PurchaseOrderType();

        pot.setCustID("1111");
        pot.setID("2121");
        pot.setProductName("Bluetooth Headset");
        pot.setItemType("Electronics");
        BigDecimal bd_p = new BigDecimal("49.99");
        pot.setPrice(bd_p);
        BigDecimal bd_q = new BigDecimal("1000");
        pot.setQuantity(bd_q);
        pot.setStatus("initial");
        pot.setCcType("Mastercard");
        pot.setCcNumber("8765-8765-8765-8765");

    }
}
```

**auto generated class ExecutePtt looks like:**

```
package com.oracle.sca.soapservice.poprocessing.poprocessing.receivepo;

import javax.jws.Oneway;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import com.oracle.xmlns.ns.order.ObjectFactory;
import com.oracle.xmlns.ns.order.PurchaseOrderType;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "execute_ptt", targetNamespace = "http://oracle.com/sca/soapservice/POProcessing/POProcessing/receivePO")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface ExecutePtt {


    /**
     * 
     * @param request
     */
    @WebMethod(action = "execute")
    @Oneway
    public void execute(
        @WebParam(name = "PurchaseOrder", targetNamespace = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/ns/order", partName = "request")
        PurchaseOrderType request);

}
```

**ReceivePO class is:**

```
package com.oracle.sca.soapservice.poprocessing.poprocessing.receivepo;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 * 
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "receivePO", targetNamespace = "http://oracle.com/sca/soapservice/POProcessing/POProcessing/receivePO", wsdlLocation = "http://i3770k.mshome.net:8001/soa-infra/services/default/POProcessing/receivePO?WSDL")
public class ReceivePO
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL RECEIVEPO_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(com.oracle.sca.soapservice.poprocessing.poprocessing.receivepo.ReceivePO.class.getName());

    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            URL baseUrl;
            baseUrl = com.oracle.sca.soapservice.poprocessing.poprocessing.receivepo.ReceivePO.class.getResource(".");
            url = new URL(baseUrl, "http://i3770k.mshome.net:8001/soa-infra/services/default/POProcessing/receivePO?WSDL");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.warning("Failed to create URL for the wsdl Location: 'http://i3770k.mshome.net:8001/soa-infra/services/default/POProcessing/receivePO?WSDL', retrying as a local file");
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
        }
        RECEIVEPO_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public ReceivePO(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public ReceivePO() {
        super(RECEIVEPO_WSDL_LOCATION, new QName("http://oracle.com/sca/soapservice/POProcessing/POProcessing/receivePO", "receivePO"));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     returns ExecutePtt
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "execute_pt")
    public ExecutePtt getExecutePt() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://oracle.com/sca/soapservice/POProcessing/POProcessing/receivePO", "execute_pt"), ExecutePtt.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param features
     *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
     * @return
     *     returns ExecutePtt
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "execute_pt")
    public ExecutePtt getExecutePt(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://oracle.com/sca/soapservice/POProcessing/POProcessing/receivePO", "execute_pt"), ExecutePtt.class, features);
    }

}
```

**ObjectFactory class is:**

```
package com.oracle.xmlns.ns.order;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


/**
 * This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * generated in the com.oracle.xmlns.ns.order package. 
 * <p>An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically 
 * construct new instances of the Java representation 
 * for XML content. The Java representation of XML 
 * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
 * and classes representing the binding of schema 
 * type definitions, element declarations and model 
 * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are 
 * provided in this class.
 * 
 */
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _PurchaseOrder_QNAME = new QName("http://xmlns.oracle.com/ns/order", "PurchaseOrder");

    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: com.oracle.xmlns.ns.order
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link PurchaseOrderType }
     * 
     */
    public PurchaseOrderType createPurchaseOrderType() {
        return new PurchaseOrderType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link PurchaseOrderType }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/ns/order", name = "PurchaseOrder")
    public JAXBElement<PurchaseOrderType> createPurchaseOrder(PurchaseOrderType value) {
        return new JAXBElement<PurchaseOrderType>(_PurchaseOrder_QNAME, PurchaseOrderType.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

**package-info is**

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/ns/order", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.oracle.xmlns.ns.order;
```

and

**PurchaseOrderType class is**

```
package com.oracle.xmlns.ns.order;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for PurchaseOrderType complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="CustID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="ID" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="productName" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="itemType" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="price" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="quantity" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="status" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="ccType" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="ccNumber" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PurchaseOrderType", propOrder = {
    "custID",
    "id",
    "productName",
    "itemType",
    "price",
    "quantity",
    "status",
    "ccType",
    "ccNumber"
})
public class PurchaseOrderType {

    @XmlElement(name = "CustID", required = true)
    protected String custID;
    @XmlElement(name = "ID", required = true)
    protected String id;
    protected String productName;
    protected String itemType;
    protected BigDecimal price;
    protected BigDecimal quantity;
    protected String status;
    protected String ccType;
    protected String ccNumber;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the custID property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCustID() {
        return custID;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the custID property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCustID(String value) {
        this.custID = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the id property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the id property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setID(String value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the productName property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the productName property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setProductName(String value) {
        this.productName = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the itemType property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getItemType() {
        return itemType;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the itemType property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setItemType(String value) {
        this.itemType = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the price property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link BigDecimal }
     *     
     */
    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the price property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link BigDecimal }
     *     
     */
    public void setPrice(BigDecimal value) {
        this.price = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the quantity property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link BigDecimal }
     *     
     */
    public BigDecimal getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the quantity property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link BigDecimal }
     *     
     */
    public void setQuantity(BigDecimal value) {
        this.quantity = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the status property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the status property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setStatus(String value) {
        this.status = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the ccType property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCcType() {
        return ccType;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the ccType property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCcType(String value) {
        this.ccType = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the ccNumber property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCcNumber() {
        return ccNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the ccNumber property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCcNumber(String value) {
        this.ccNumber = value;
    }

}
```

Therfore my questions are:

1. What should I add in my class SOAClient to make this work (set the parameters and execute test - place order)
2. Should I use JAX-WS at all? I ask because i saw some tutorials without it but i haven't still studied them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once when I found it, solution looks quite easy.
Here is the class that did the job right:

```
package com.oracle.client;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import com.oracle.sca.soapservice.poprocessing.poprocessing.receivepo.ExecutePtt;
import com.oracle.sca.soapservice.poprocessing.poprocessing.receivepo.ReceivePO;
import com.oracle.xmlns.ns.order.ObjectFactory;
import com.oracle.xmlns.ns.order.PurchaseOrderType;

public class SOAClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ReceivePO recPOService = new ReceivePO();
        ExecutePtt recPOPort = recPOService.getExecutePt();
        PurchaseOrderType purchaseOrder = new ObjectFactory()
                .createPurchaseOrderType();

        purchaseOrder.setCustID("1111");
        purchaseOrder.setID("2121");
        purchaseOrder.setProductName("Bluetooth Headset");
        purchaseOrder.setItemType("Electronics");
        BigDecimal bd_p = new BigDecimal("49.99");
        purchaseOrder.setPrice(bd_p);
        BigDecimal bd_q = new BigDecimal("10");
        purchaseOrder.setQuantity(bd_q);
        purchaseOrder.setStatus("initial");
        purchaseOrder.setCcType("Mastercard");
        purchaseOrder.setCcNumber("8765-8765-8765-8765");

        recPOPort.execute(purchaseOrder);

    }
}
```